# SQL Sort by Sequence

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table that I'm trying to sort and am having some difficulties. 
It's a sequence column that is meant to represent hierarchical data, which automatically sorts as shown below:

```
SEQUENCE 
1
1.1
1.10
1.2
1.3    
...
2
2.1
```

And instead I need to to sort like:

```
SEQUENCE 
1
1.1
1.2
...
1.10
2
2.1
```

It's in MS Access, and it's a local (temp) table, so I don't have access to hierarchyID or any other cool MS-SQL tools. Also, there isn't a fixed level of the sequence, so I can't just split them readily into columns. Any ideas?

CLARIFICATION: There is not a set level of the sequence, and it's not confined to two parts. It will often be 5+ (e.g. 1.1.1.1.1).

Comment: It's already a string, and the cstr(sequence) just gives the same result as in the first part, not the second. 1.10 as a string comes before 1.2, and I need 1.2 to come before 1.10

Comment: The sort follows alpha rules. Either need placeholder zeros to force numeric-like sort (1.01, 1.02 ... 1.10) or parse the string to discrete number parts that can be sorted numerically. You show only 2 levels. Is that all? Use string manipulation functions - Left, Mid, InStr. Might need a VBA custom function to accomplish if the structure is too complex.

Comment: You'll have to split that value into two parts (let's call them "left" and "right", for example: for 1.10, left = 1 and right = 10), convert each of them to NUMBER and then sort by them, separately (order by to_nubmer(left), to_number(right)). If Access supports regular expressions, that's rather easy. Otherwise, use SUBSTR(ing) function or whatever you can.  Sorry for not being able to actually write it as I don't know Access syntax, but - that's the general idea, I hope it'll help.

Comment: There can be more than two levels, there isn't a fixed level and it can be 5+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the value between the major and minor version, cast them to numeric, and order by both.

Splitting in Access SQL is hard, though. If you're going for 3-part or more-part version numbers, I recommend you use VBA.

```
SELECT Sequence
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY 
CInt(IIF(Sequence LIKE "*.*", Left(SEQUENCE, Instr(1, SEQUENCE, ".")-1)),
IIF(IsNumeric(Right(Sequence, Len(SEQUENCE) - Instr(1, SEQUENCE, "."))), CINT(Right(Sequence, Len(SEQUENCE) - Instr(1, SEQUENCE, "."))) ,0))
```

Comment: Dang. I was hoping there was a cool trick to this (like a hierarchyID equivalent) that I just didn't know. I have no problem using VBA, and it looks like that's what I'll have to do because these can be 5+ parts. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For two-part hierachy values, you could use something like this:

```
SELECT Sequence 
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY Int(Sequence), Int(Replace(Sequence,".","0"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can *order by* this fancy expression using *Val*:

```
Int(Val([Sequence])), Val(Mid([Sequence], 1 + Len(Str(Int(Val([Sequence]))))))
```

It will also behave for paragraphs above 9:

```
1
1.1
1.2
...
1.10
2
2.1
...
10.0
10.11
```

Answer (score 0):

Because I'm limited to MS Access SQL functionality, and the sequence isn't limited to a two-part structure, I ended up taking June7's suggestion to just add zeros when I make the table, so that it sorts correctly just using a simple ORDER BY.

Thanks everyone for your help.